# Как не сортировать объет по ключу в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Как пройтись по объекту в цикле?

Я понимаю что нужно использовать массив объектов, а есть вариант без массива объектов?

```js
let obj = {'0': 0, '12.5': 'для примера', '25.8': [], '100': true}

console.log(obj);
console.log(Object.values(obj));
console.log(Object.entries(obj));

Object.values(obj).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: А суть проблемы в чём?

Comment: В цикле нужно чтобы после 0 шло 12.5 и тд

Comment: Так не сортировать или пройтись? Для не сортировать нет никаких вариантов. Порядок обхода ключей строго описан в спецификации и 0, 100 всегда будут идти до 12.5, 25.8. Хочешь сохранять порядок — используй массивы или Map-ы

Comment: У вас в хэше ключ совпадает со значением, а вам нужно непременно сортировать по значению, так?

Comment: @Alexey тоесть вообще без вариантов, придется менять объект на массив объектов? на такой? `[{'0': 0}, {'12.5': 12.5}, {'25.8': 25.8}, {'100': 100}]`

Comment: Зависит от задачи. В вашем абстрактном примере вообще непонятно зачем объект нужен.

Comment: Просто в таком виде я его получаю, а нужно строгая сортировка

Comment: Ну возьмите значения и отсортируйте…

Comment: @Alexey, а как? нужно чтобы в цикле было '0' '12.5'... и тд, а то сейчас там '0' '100'...

Comment: Ну возьмите значения и **отсортируйте**…

Comment: А если значение это для примера, и там объекты, строки и тд, а нужно в цикле именно по ключу?

Comment: Ну и зачем показывать примеры бесполезные и не имеющие отношение к реальности? Просите у того кто их вам там отдаёт что бы отдавал нормальный массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {'0': 0, '12.5': 'для примера', '25.8': [], '100': true}

console.log(obj);
console.log(Object.values(obj));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log(Object.entries(obj));

let propertyName = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) 
propertyName.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
console.log(propertyName)

propertyName.forEach(index => {
    console.log(obj[index])
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]